# Что означает слово "Сибирь"?

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Что означает слово "Сибирь" и от какого слова происходит название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно не известно, от какого слова происходит название Сибирь. Есть версии, что это тюркское слово, происходящее от слова "метель" (сэбэр), или монгольское "шибир" - "низменное место". Есть версия, что это просто искаженное русское слово "север".

Answer (score 1):

Масса версий. Часть их них (не все, видимо) можно найти в Вики.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8C

Стоит упомянуть как установленный факт, что до XIII века название относилось к народу (народам), там проживавшему. И только впоследствии - к самому региону.

Answer (score 1):

Слово `Сибирь` по Гумилеву (Льву, а не Николаю естественно) происходит от самоназвания народа `Сяньби` (тунгусо-маньчжурского происхождения). Сяньби жили на границе Забайкальских степей и Сибирских лесов примерно в 3, 4-м веке д.н.э. и впоследствии завоевали Ханьскую империю и в середине 4,5-го веков полностью окитаились.